# How to use TypeScript definitions @types in ionic2 project

Tags: typescript, ionic2, google-api-js-client

Ionic2 now use @types to support for third-party libraries.

I installed

```
npm install --save @types/gapi.auth2
```

But I don't know how to add my project to use it. Please help me

Answer (score 1):

It should be pretty easy after you have installed @types/gapi.auth2, just add in your `tsconfig.json` in `compilerOptions` section the following line:

```
"types": ["gapi.auth2"]
```

And make sure you are using typescript 2.x

Hope this helps.

Comment: how I can use it in project after importing? Example, do I need import again in code, like `import { GoogleAuth } from '@types/gapi.auth2';` ?

Comment: yes you should import it like this: `import { GoogleAuth } from 'gapi.auth2';`

Comment: I try import { GoogleAuth } from 'gapi.auth2' after adding to tsconfig.json but it has error?

Comment: The reason is that you have added definitions only - that will allow your program to compile and pass through all type checks. The module itself is missing - you have to instruct your module loader how to find and load it. I have no experience with ionic2 - but try checking this thread as a sample of systemjs configuration: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/8215

Comment: you ide should support typescript 2.0